# VisualStudio Autocomplete function params like Xcode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio version 7.7.3 with C#. Is there a way to configure my autocomplete settings to complete functions parameters like Xcode?

In Xcode, when I define a function:

```
func foo(bar: Int, baz: Int) {
}
```

Then type "f" then autocomplete key I get:

```
foo(bar: <#T##Int#>, baz: <#T##Int#>) // 2 key strokes
```

However, if I define the same function in C# with Visual Studio then type "f" then autocomplete I get:

```
foo  //need to manually add parameter names, no placeholder types
```

I want Visual Studio to automatically add the parameter names and/or placeholder types like the first example. I found mentions of a setting called "useCodeSnippetsOnMethodSuggest" but it seems like it's specific to using VS with typescript (not c#). Is there another way to accomplish this using VS with C# or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try to create a custom code snippet to achieve this requirement, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

You may try Resharper or CodeRush extensions, if they do not work as you want, you can set a predefined templates for autocomplete.

I personally prefer the Resharper.

Comment: Do those extensions enable the functionality I need out of the box or do I need to configure a setting for it?  Regardless I'll check them out. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinCarter I'm not so sure but I hope it helps you